# OFDM in multipath channel simulation in it++

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, multipath

I am trying to simulate OFDM for an multi-path channel. I am using [it++](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/4.3.1/) for simulation.

```
transmit_bits = randb(FrameLength);                   //The frame bits. 1024
coded_bits = conv_code.encode(transmit_bits);    //The convolutional encoder function.

modulator->modulate_bits(coded_bits, trans_symbols); //The  modulator.

ofdm.set_parameters(trans_symbols.size(), 100);
trans_symbols = ofdm.modulate(trans_symbols);

rec_symbols = channel(trans_symbols, coeff);        //The TDL channel.

rec_symbols = ofdm.demodulate(rec_symbols.split(trans_symbols.size()));

modulator->demodulate_soft_bits(rec_symbols, 0, recived_bits);  //Demodulate
decoded_bits = conv_code.decode(recived_bits);   //The decoder function.

berc.count(transmit_bits, decoded_bits);
```

I am always getting an BER of around 0.5. what am i doing wrong? Also after passing through channel, the length of the ofdm symbols will increase (due to multipath), currently i am blindly removing the extra bits, Is it the wright thing to do?

Comment: If you get BER of 0.5 this means that actually the RX signal is completely independent of the TX signal, i.e. you have a serious bug in the implementation. Go through the documentation of each block, debug the input-output relations of each block. Start small with connecting encoder directly with decoder. Remove the channel in between. Go step by step.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé  If i remove the TDL channel and replace it with a awgn channel, the BER is 0.0002

Comment: So, you are missing channel equalization.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé So should i do OFDM and equalization too ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you want be able to receive it correctly. Also, check if you have a CP added, otherwise the standard equalization one-tap equalization for OFDM wont work. You might have a look e.g. [here](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/python-ofdm-example.html?rid=so5) though it's in python (Disclaimer: I wrote this article, on my website) on how channel equalization is done or [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/what-does-the-one-tap-equalizer-used-with-ofdm-accomplish). Also, you need to know the channel (or estimate it from the received signal).